# Sorting by values in a sublist in python

Tags: python, sorting

My list contains a number of elements in this format

```
(23, (12,16,42))
```

my rudimentary sort right now will sort by the first value in the sublist by default.

```
value = sorted(list, key=itemgetter(1))
```

I want to use a second level sort option as described http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

```
sorted(student_tuples, key=itemgetter(1,2))
```

So is there an address for each of the items in the sublist?  I've tried to find some bracket or colon notation and just haven't spotted it yet I assume.

Example unsorted list

```
(0, (81.0, 5.0, 83.0)), (1, (81.0, 1.0, 26.0)), (2, (80.0, 1.0, 44.0)),
```

the output would be similar to

```
(2, (80.0, 1.0, 44.0)), (1, (81.0, 1.0, 26.0)), (0, (81.0, 5.0, 83.0))

(w, (x,y,z))
```

so the first sort is on x.  If there are multiple x values, it sorts them by y

Comment: Can you provide an example of a list, the result you get and the result you expect?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
>>> a = [23, [5, 6, 7]]
>>> a[1][0]
5
```

The sublist is an item, so you use one set of brackets to get that sublist, and then another to index into the sublist.

Comment: value = sorted(list, key=itemgetter(1[0],1[1])) didn't work for me

Comment: Er, okay, maybe you misunderstood. `itemgetter` is still only designed for flat lists - the `itemgetter(1,2)` just says to sort first by field index 1, and then for equivalent values there, by field index 2. It doesn't have any extra depth; the "levels" is misleading.

Answer (score 4):

Define it yourself:

```
sorted(list, key=lambda item: item[0][1])
# or whatever other sort of indexing you want
```

In your case, the indexing you want is:

```
sorted(list, key=lambda item: (item[1][0], item[1][1]))
```

since comparing tuples works by comparing elements pairwise. `key` is any callable that transforms the items into a thing that can be compared directly in order to get the desired comparison results.

Comment: I've updated the question to contain more detail.  The goal is to sort by both the first and the second value of the sublist, not only the first

Comment: Edited accordingly with a bit more explanation. - But better yet, see gnibbler's response.

Answer (score 2):

The general way to sort by multiple properties, is to have a key function that returns a tuple. This works because Python sorts tuples from left to right, so it sounds like you are trying to do this

```
>>> L=(0, (81.0, 5.0, 83.0)), (1, (81.0, 1.0, 26.0)), (2, (80.0, 1.0, 44.0)),
>>> sorted(L, key=lambda x:(x[1][0],x[1][1]))
[(2, (80.0, 1.0, 44.0)), (1, (81.0, 1.0, 26.0)), (0, (81.0, 5.0, 83.0))]
```

Since the order of the fields you want to sort by is the same as the order in the tuple, you can simplify to this

```
>>> sorted(L, key=lambda x:x[1])
[(2, (80.0, 1.0, 44.0)), (1, (81.0, 1.0, 26.0)), (0, (81.0, 5.0, 83.0))]
```

Which gets you back to simply

```
>>> sorted(L, key=itemgetter(1))
[(2, (80.0, 1.0, 44.0)), (1, (81.0, 1.0, 26.0)), (0, (81.0, 5.0, 83.0))]
```

But hopefully now you can see why this *does* sort on the elements in the order you desire